# simple C error - #include?

Tags: c

I'm using textpad on Windows 8, installed MinGW for compiling C

Not sure why this is causing trouble:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    printf("To C, or not to C: that is the question.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The error says

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C files\pun.c:1:2: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
 #
  ^
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C files\pun.c:1:3: error: invalid preprocessing directive #i
 #
   ^

cc1.exe: out of memory allocating 838860800 bytes

Tool completed with exit code 1
```

Comment: It's possible that your file starts with a BOM header (if it's "Unicode Text" under Windows, especially). Make sure it doesn't.

Comment: ... and similarly make sure you haven't saved as UTF-16. That'd explain an apparently NULL character jumping in there.

Comment: Yeah, make sure you save it as UTF-8 or "ANSI text" or the like.

Answer (score 3):

You've almost certainly saved your file with one of the Unicode encodings such as `UTF-16`.

This assigns 16 bits to each character meaning that if you hes-dump your code, you'll see something like:

```
0000 - 23 00 69 00 6e 00 63 00 - 6c 00 75 00 64 00 5 00 - #.i.n.c.l.u.d.e.
```

at the start.

A compiler that *doesn't* understand UTF-16 will then probably complain bitterly about finding null bytes amongst all the real characters, just as yours seems to have done.

To fix it, either save the file in a more conventional form (such as ASCII) or find a compiler that can handle it. The former is probably the easier path to take provided you don't actually *need* all those non-ASCII Unicode characters.